# compare datatable and remove duplicates in vb.net

Tags: datatable, vb.net-2010

am using two datatable named as dnddatatable and dtdup . it contains set of phone numbers . I want to compare 2nd datatable with first datatable and remove the values from datatable1(name as dnddatatable)values which are equal to 2nd datatable name as(dtdup).

```
data in the datatable as follows.

dnddatatable(data table1)

phone
9865015695
9840903331 
98668625
800971868
809679532
837445478

dtdup(dtata table2)

phone_numbers
9865015695
9840903331 

result dnddatatable(data table1)

98668625
800971868
809679532
837445478
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a pretty similar question time ago, the idea is exactly the same

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        For j As Integer = 0 To dataset1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString = dataset1.Tables(0).Rows(j)    (0).ToString Then
                found = True
            End If
        Next
        If found = False Then
            'here you are getting the right result in each loop
            'in this example i'm showing the result in a textbox
            'just change the instruction and write them in your note pad or wherever you want to
            MsgBox(dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString)
        End If
    Next
```